# Como buscar o usuário logado na camada Infra? (Usando DDD com EF em C# MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, ddd

Estou desenvolvendo uma funcionalidade de armazenamento do histórico de modificações dos registros de tela. Exemplo: Tenho um cadastro de pessoas, nesse cadastro de pessoas, a cada ação realizada (Insert, Edit, Delete) eu guardo em banco via JSON os dados da entidade naquele momento. Isso me dará todo o histórico de modificações realizadas no decorrer do tempo.
Até aí está fluindo bem, porém eu preciso gravar o usuário que realizou a operação, nesse caso na camada Infra eu não tenho o usuário logado e sim somente na cama de UI.

Estou usando EF (como ORM) e Identity(para controle de acessos), o Identity está em um projeto isolado na infra.

Uma solução seria eu sempre transportar nas viewmodel para o domínio o usuário logado, porém é inviável fazer isso... sendo que foge de qualquer boa prática, ou seja, eu deixaria na mão do programador o controle de sempre estar passando o usuário logado.

Outra solução seria criar nos filters um filter de auditoria. Porém nesse momento eu não consigo controlar sempre todos os dados, pois nem sempre minhas operações transportam a viewmodel para camada de serviço ou domínio e fica complexo de controlar se o domínio aceitou as validações de regras de negócios.
Descartei o modelo.

Vi saída em sobrescrever o SaveChanges do EF na camada de Infra, adicionado um método para realizar o registro de log. Porém na camada de Infra eu não possuo o acesso à recuperar o usuário logado.

Meu questionamento: 
Como posso recuperar o Usuário logado na Infra?
E como vocês lidam com histórico de alterações dos registros em suas aplicações?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode incluir no construtor da classe responsável por fazer o trabalho com o ORM  (Ou sem ORM também) o parâmetro com o o ID do usuário logado, e na camada de mapeamento da injeção de dependência você instancia a a camada de UI e chama um método que retorna o usuário logado, e passa no parâmetro ID do usuário no próprio mapeamento da injeção de dependência, feito isso ninguém precisará se preocupar em estar sempre passando tal parâmetro, você terá ele como parâmetro sempre que acionado algum método da classe responsável por fazer qualquer alteração no banco.

Comment: Interessante a solução, vou implementar e volto a comentar aqui a resolução. Por enquanto, Obrigado!

Comment: A solução dada não deu certo pois da referência circular. A minha UI possui referência do Ioc. Preciso achar outra solução para o caso.